# Chrome extension: Identifying "actual" tabs from webNavigation events

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to identify if a tab for which I received "webNavigation.onCompleted" is an "actual" tab.

As described in the documentation:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html

A short quote from the docs:

*A note about tab IDs : 
Not all navigating tabs correspond to **actual tabs** in Chrome's UI, e.g., a tab that is being pre-rendered. Such tabs are not accessible via the tabs API nor can you request information about them via webNavigation.getFrame or webNavigation.getAllFrames. Once such a tab is swapped in, an onTabReplaced event is fired and they become accessible via these APIs.*

So now when I get an event I encounter 2 problems when trying to figure out if the tab is "actual":

1. The scenario as described in the documentation, however I see that onTabReplaced can called before/after onCompleted,
   or even not called even though I expect it to be called since I dont have the tab id in a list of tabs I create in tabs.onCreate,
   and later the page is displayed in a tab.
2. Pages that are pre-rendered in Google chrome pages (e.g google for "ford"), and eventually dont become to show on tabs.

In case you're not familiar with pre-rendering:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1385029?hl=en

I consider these cases to be different because I see in difference in pre-rendered pages,
that end u to be tads, and the ones who are not used eventually.
One page is eventually "navigated to", while the other on is just "cached".

But this difference can not be detected by using the webNavigation api, as far I as could find.

So my question - is there any way to distinguish (hopefully using the webNaviagtion api),
between an "actual" tab, a pre-rendered page which is going to be displayed as tab,
and a pre-rendered page that is going stay in cache (for now) ?

Just 2 clarifications, about solutions that supposedly I can use, but they look to me "not good",
at least at this stage.

1. The docs say "Such tabs are not accessible via the tabs API".
   so technically I can try an use this API, get an exception, and this way figure out it's "pre-renderd" tab,
   but I dont like my code to use exceptions for this, so I'm looking for a "clean" way.
2. in webNavigation.onComplete, I can set a timeout for 1 second,
   and then if in this one second, onTabReplaced, I can figure out that this tab was
   moved to be an "actual" tab. and not stayed in "cache".
   But during this 1 second, or any duration I choose, there can be a lot of other events,
   and even the tab can be closed.
   So again, I'm looking for a "clean" solution.

Thanks for your help.